# How to integrate of two variables

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Can anyone help me how to solve for $z(x)$ in the equation below.
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{z(x)}\cdot \frac{dz(x)}{dx}$$

Thanks

Comment: Write $y(x)dx=\dfrac{1}{z(x)}dz(x)$ and integrate both sides!

Answer (score 0):

The right-hand side is the derivative of $\log z(x)$, so integrating you will get
$$
\log z(x)=\int y(x)\,dx
$$
which means that
$$
z(x)=\exp\biggl(\int y(x)\,dx\biggr).
$$
I think this is the closest you can get without more information.